# Sprite follow another flexible way within certain distance limits

Tags: python, pygame, 2d-games, 2d-vector

I'm trying to make sprite to follow another sprite flexible way.

If main sprite moves faster follower gets more behind, and if slower follower gets closer.

Movement itself works with following (pseudo) code:

```
target_vector = Vector2D(mainsprite_x, mainsprite_y)
follower_vector = Vector2D(follower_x, follower_y)

new_follower_vector = Vector2D.lerp(follower_vector, target_vector, LERP_FACTOR)
```

Currently I've been using various constants for `LERP_FACTOR` which works "okayish".

Now I would like to add limits how much behind follower can be and how close it can get.

I'm using Pygame but that shouldn't matter.

How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to compute the distance from between the follower and the sprite and the unit direction vector from (`follower_x`, `follower_y`) to (`mainsprite_x`, `mainsprite_y`).
The distance can be get by computing the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). Pygame provides [`distance_to()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to) for that. Th unit direction vector can be computed by dividing the direction vector by the distance or by normalizing ([`normalize()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.normalize)) the direction vector:

```py
target_vector = Vector2(mainsprite_x, mainsprite_y)
follower_vector = Vector2(follower_x, follower_y)

distance = follower_vector.distance_to(target_vector)
direction_vector = target_vector - follower_vector
if distance > 0:
    direction_vector /= distance
```

Now you can define an exact `step_distance` and move to follower int direction of the sprite:

```py
if distance > 0:
    new_follower_vector = follower_vector + direction_vector * step_distance.
```

Define a `maximum_distance` and a `minimum_distance`. The minimum step distance is:

```py
min_step = max(0, distance - maximum_distance)
```

The maximum  step distance is

```py
max_step = distance - minimum_distance
```

Put it all together:

```py
minimum_distance    = ???
maximum_distance    = ???
target_vector       = Vector2(mainsprite_x, mainsprite_y)
follower_vector     = Vector2(follower_x, follower_y)
new_follower_vector = Vector2(follower_x, follower_y)

distance = follower_vector.distance_to(target_vector)
if distance > minimum_distance:
    direction_vector    = (target_vector - follower_vector) / distance
    min_step            = max(0, distance - maximum_distance)
    max_step            = distance - minimum_distance
    step_distance       = min_step + (max_step - min_step) * LERP_FACTOR
    new_follower_vector = follower_vector + direction_vector * step_distance
```

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-FollowMouseSmoothly](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-FollowMouseSmoothly#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

LERP_FACTOR      = 0.05
minimum_distance = 25
maximum_distance = 100

def FollowMe(pops, fpos):
    target_vector       = pygame.math.Vector2(*pops)
    follower_vector     = pygame.math.Vector2(*fpos)
    new_follower_vector = pygame.math.Vector2(*fpos)

    distance = follower_vector.distance_to(target_vector)
    if distance > minimum_distance:
        direction_vector    = (target_vector - follower_vector) / distance
        min_step            = max(0, distance - maximum_distance)
        max_step            = distance - minimum_distance
        step_distance       = min_step + (max_step - min_step) * LERP_FACTOR
        new_follower_vector = follower_vector + direction_vector * step_distance

    return (new_follower_vector.x, new_follower_vector.y) 

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

follower = (100, 100)
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    player   = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    follower = FollowMe(player, follower)

    window.fill(0)  
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (0, 0, 255), player, 10)
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 0, 0), (round(follower[0]), round(follower[1])), 10)
    pygame.display.flip()
```